# iphone tab bar design dilemma

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, tabs

I have to make an app for client where there are functionalities best defined by tab bar interface. I am no UI designer but I have done some basic research and read the Human Interface Guidelines by Apple. Another point is that app deals extensively with Web Services and user has to login before using any of the features of the app. The user needs to login only first time and app will call the login API second time onwards whenever the app is tapped on from home screen. Now if password is changed, login would fail and ask user to login again but if login is successful, it would directly present the tab bar interface by-passing the login screen. My dilemma is designing the starting screen.

I am confused between two approaches.

1. Have a stand alone login screen (like in facebook app) and present the tab bar once login is done. In this approach tab bar can be presented modally but it remains there for the life cycle of the application (say 5-10 mins max) which in-turn involves other modal views for filling forms etc. Would this be a good approach presenting tab bar modally when it is going to be the main interface of the app? Also another approach is flip the login screen to present tab bar
2. Second approach is have "login" as one of the tabs of the tab bar and dsiable other tabs till login process is completed. Once logged in successfully, make other tabs active and may be change the numbering of tabs and move "login" tab (probably renaming the title to "logout" at the end of the tab list. Would this be overly complicated to achieve?

Or is there a better 3rd approach to tackle this? Need your suggestions desperately on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something similar to dropbox app. It also uses tab bar interface and also depends on web authentication.

If use is not logged in display a choice to register or use existing account. No tab bar interface, can be based solely on navigation items. Then once user log in successfully display tab bar interface. Somewhere in Settings let the user to logout. In case of dropbox it will just shut down application once "unlinked". You can do the same or switch to original login navigation screen by flipping tab bar.

That's pretty much it,
Hope it helps.

Comment: will check out the app ... looks like that should do it for me ... thanks :)